# Javascript: Saving .innerHTML Data with a Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to Javascript and I'm trying to learn to create a simple Tic Tac Toe program. I'm not concerned with refactoring at this stage, but getting the basic elements to work. Here's the code:

```
 window.onload = function() {
  // Establish the boxes for the selector
  var boxOne = document.querySelector("#b1");

  // Create an event when a box is clicked
  boxOne.onclick = function() {
    if (boxOne.innerHTML === "X") {
        boxOne.innerHTML = "O";
    } else {
        boxOne.innerHTML = "X";
    }

  }

  // Check the current innerHTML of the grid for a win.
  var b1 = boxOne.innerHTML,
      b2 = boxTwo.innerHTML,
      b3 = boxThree.innerHTML,
      b4 = boxFour.innerHTML,
      b5 = boxFive.innerHTML,
      b6 = boxSix.innerHTML,
      b7 = boxSeven.innerHTML,
      b8 = boxEight.innerHTML,
      b9 = boxNine.innerHTML;

  var board = [
    [b1, b2, b3],
    [b4, b5, b6],
    [b7, b8, b9]
    ];

  endButton.onclick = function() {
    console.log(board);
  }

  var clearButton = document.getElementById('clear');
  var allBoxes = document.querySelector(".box");

  clearButton.onclick = function() {
    allBoxes.innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

The player should be able to click a box to choose X or O. I then want them to click 'End Turn' so that the game can check the current status of the board and report a win condition if necessary.

However, it doesn't seem to be saving the player input. When I invoke '.innerHTML' it just returns a blank array. Yet if I look at the browser console I see that the '.innerHTML' element has an X or O in it. So the data is there, but it isn't being input into the array. I've tried to test this on different implementations of it, but the array remains blank.

The "Clear" button is also not working. Everything I've Google'd so far uses what I have here as an example to clear HTML input from an element.

Can anyone help me understand what's wrong with my code? Thank you.

Additional Info:
You can review all of my current working files [here on Github](https://github.com/Protosac/tictactoe), which includes the HTML, CSS and JS documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code lies in the logic; You have several variables (boxOne..boxNine, b1..b9, board). You instantiate those variables alright, but you only change the boxOne..boxNine variables in the onclick events. Moreover, you never update the board after you instantiate it (that's why it's always blank when you click the 'end turn' button).

Your endButton.onclick function should be changed to this to make it work;

```
endButton.onclick = function() {
  // Check the current innerHTML of the grid for a win.
  var b1 = boxOne.innerHTML,
  b2 = boxTwo.innerHTML,
  b3 = boxThree.innerHTML,
  b4 = boxFour.innerHTML,
  b5 = boxFive.innerHTML,
  b6 = boxSix.innerHTML,
  b7 = boxSeven.innerHTML,
  b8 = boxEight.innerHTML,
  b9 = boxNine.innerHTML;

  var board = [
   [b1, b2, b3],
   [b4, b5, b6],
   [b7, b8, b9]
  ];
  console.log(board);
}
```

However, your javascript needs some cleaning, to avoid repeating yourself;

```
window.onload = function() {

// Instantiate board
var board = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    board[i].onclick = function() {
        this.innerHTML = (this.innerHTML === 'X')? 'O' : 'X';
    }
}

// A function to render the board
var renderBoard = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        this.innerHTML = 'X';
    }
}

// End turn
var endButton = document.getElementById('endturn');
endButton.onclick = function() {
    // Do magic
}

// Clear board
var clearButton = document.getElementById('clear');
clear.onclick = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        board[i].innerHTML = '';
    }
}

renderBoard();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback on the order and placement of the variables! That did the trick. I would not have thought that was the problem. Also I appreciate the refactor offer, but as mentioned  I'm not worried about refactoring or direct solutions. I just need to understand what I have and what it actually does so I can figure it out as much as I can on my own. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding what innerHTML is. When you do `b1 = boxOne.innerHTML`, you are storing the string that is the current html in `b1`. You are not storing a reference to the innerHTML property. So, when you do `boxOne.innerHTML = 'X'`, you change the inner html of the object but `b1` still holds whatever the inner HTML was originally.

An example to clarify my statement:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // Establish the boxes for the selector
  var boxOne = document.querySelector("#b1");

  // initialInnerHTML won't change when you change boxOne.innerHTML
  var initialInnerHTML = boxOne.innerHTML;

  boxOne.innerHTML = '<a>New link</a>'; // Change the dom content
  var newInnerHTML = boxOne.innerHTML;

  alert(initialInnerHTML); // Alerts a blank dialog
  alert(newInnerHTML); // Alerts "<a>New link</a>"


  // An example of storing a reference to an object
  var shoppingCart = {
          apples: { price: 6, quantity: 7 },
          oranges: { price: 10, quantity: 8 }
      };
  var appleReference = shoppingCart.apples;

  alert(appleReference.quantity); // Alerts 7

  shoppingCart.apples.quantity = 9;

  alert(appleReference.quantity); // Alerts 9

}
```

To fix your issue, you need to get the innerHTML property of the dom elements on each button press instead of doing it only when the page is loaded.

Your second issue is because `document.querySelector('.box')` only returns the first dom element that matches the selector. You should use `document.querySelectorAll('.box')` which returns an array of the elements. Then, loop over the array and set the innerHTML on each one.

clear button:

```
  var clearButton = document.getElementById('clear');
  var allBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");

  clearButton.onclick = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < allBoxes.length; i++){
        allBoxes[i].innerHTML = "";
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't follow your first statement. The comment above yours solves the issue i had with saving player input with the "End Turn" button, so the values are currently being stored. Also not following your instruction on the "Clear" button. I tried 'document.querSelectorAll' to no avail. It still doesn't clear the contents of the grid. Is that code, as I have written it, working on your end when you test it? Can you be a bit more clearer on exactly which button configuration you're explaining and perhaps an example? Thank you for your help so far, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also added example script to clarify my first statement.

Comment: I see what you mean now, and it makes sense now that you pointed that out. Thanks! I actually have another question related to the same code. Is it appropriate to edit the original to just add it in or should I post a new question altogether?

Comment: Its probably better to create a new question